# Tab Validation for Required Field in MVC4 Razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to implement tab validation in MVC.I have two textbox Password and Confirm Password and Confirm Password should be same as Password .Till Now I have done with Compare Validation and it is validating perfectly but I am getting Validation message only when Form is submitting.
I want to do on Tab means after entering Confirm Password on tab if it is not same as Password I want Validation Message any approach I want to use either jquery or javascript.Can someone please help me to do this.I am sharing my code.

View

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "SaveInfo", FormMethod.Post))
        {
          @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <div style="color:red; text-align:center" >
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Validation Summary</legend>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
               <br />
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.ConfirmPassword)
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div>
              <table border="1" style=  "width:500px">
                  <tr>
                      <td>
                          @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Password) 
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { style="Width:300px"})

                      </td>

                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>
                          @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.ConfirmPassword)
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { style="Width:300px"})
                      </td>

                  </tr>
                 </table>
              <input type="submit" value="Save"  />
          </div>

        }
```

Model

```
                          using System;
                using System.Collections.Generic;
                using System.Linq;
                using System.Web;
                using System.Data;
                using System.Data.SqlClient;
                using System.Configuration;
                using System.ComponentModel;
                using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

                namespace Employee_Mgmt_System.Models
                {
                    public class EmployeeRegistration
                    {

                        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password Cannot be kept blank")]
                        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
                        [Display(Name = "Password")]
                        public string Password
                        {
                            get;
                            set;
                        }
                        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirm Password Cannot be kept blank")]
                        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
                        [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
                        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Password and confirm password is not matching")]
                        public string ConfirmPassword
                        {
                            get;
                            set;
                        }


                    }

                }
```

Comment: please show you model.cs

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2010/08/06/asp-net-mvc-adding-client-side-validation-to-propertiesmustmatchattribute.aspx chek this

Comment: @Nitin I want to Validate on Tab using jquery.I want to remove that model Valiadtion Piece of Code the link you have given there is no where mentioned to use client side

Answer (score 0):

Try it:-

I an using  of jquery it may help you.

```
jQuery('.validatedForm').validate({
    rules : {
        password : {
            minlength : 5
        },
        password_confirm : {
            minlength : 5,
            equalTo : "#password"
        }
    }
});
```

[JSfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fEZFB/183/)

I think so there should be something like it.

Comment: its not working for me and I am using jquery jquery-ui-1.8.20.

Comment: Add `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>` of behalf of your jquery-ui1.8... it will work.And whenever we use jquery-ui then it is only for ui purpose but whenever we want to use of jquery code then we have need to add jquery.js file.For more information follow this link http://www.w3schools.com/Jquery/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

Check this if u can use `Jquery keyup` event

```
 <tr>
                          <td>
                              @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Password) 
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { style="Width:300px",@id="pwd"})

                          </td>

                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>
                              @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.ConfirmPassword)
                          </td>
                          <td>


                              @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { style="Width:300px",@id="confpwd"})
                          </td>
                  <tr>
                  <td>
                   <label id="msgerror"/>
                          </td>

                    </tr>

$('#pwd,#confpwd').keyup(function(){
if($('#pwd').val()!=$('#confpwd').val())
    $('#msgerror').text('Must match');
    else
        $('#msgerror').text('');

})
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7PGnU/1/)